# Jenkins - run concurrent builds with pararrel stages one per node/agent

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, jenkins-pipeline

I have job with pararrel steps which checks pull requests before making a vote for merge. Lets say it looks like this:

1. GIT step (pulls specific commit)
2. (in main dir)
   2a. 'npm install' step
   2b. 'npm run frontend tests'
3. (in /simulator dir)
   3a. 'pip install -r requirements'
   3b. 'run python tests.
4. Make a vote and notify with slack

2 and 3 are running pararrel.

My nodes are labeled brix2 and brix3, their common label  is brix. Each has 4 executors.

I want that:

1. When first job is running, it runs entirely on brix2 - both pararrel steps should use 2 executors of brix2.
2. When second job is running and brix2 is busy it takes brix3 to use - same way as above, pararrel on 2 executors
3. When 3 job is running and brix2 and brix3 are busy, it goes to queue

What i tried:

- When i use common label first job is simultaneusly running both on
  brix2 and brix3.
- If i enable "Dont allow run concurrent builds" then it runs only one build at time, and adds the rest to queue even though 1 node is free.
- If i use Throttling Concurrent Builds plugin (set on 2 nodes) it spreads my pararrel steps to both nodes, so pt2 is running on brix2 and pt3 is running on brix3. I want to run them on one machine, the same workspace, but different folders.

Ive also tried to spread the tasks manually in upstream job by checking if agents executors are idle. And i can give first two build jobs to brix2 and brix3, but third and later requests (when b2 and b3 are busy) should go to queue and i dont know how to do that

Ive also read about lock() step which can lock resources. I would love to lock all 4 executors on the node im running now for the entire pipeline. But is it the way it should be done?

I mean, my pipeline seems to me a very common way of building stuff, not something exotic which need some complicated hacks. For such things Jenkins should have ready solutions so im feeling im doing something not the way it should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is that your nodes should only have one executor each.  You can do steps in parallel on one node - so just do that for steps 2 and 3.  Job 1 would start on brix2 and run any steps it wants in parallel, Job 2 on brix3 and Job 3 would need to wait for one of those nodes to finish before it begins.